# Error while creating GCP Serverless VPC Connection ("code": 13)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

Trying to create a serverless VPC connection but always getting the same error

**ERROR: (gcloud.compute.networks.vpc-access.connectors.create) {
"code": 13,
"message": "An internal error occurred: Failed to create a VPC Access connector. Please delete the connector
}**

Have tried the following

1. Reference Link: [Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access)
2. Tried all steps in [Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#troubleshooting) - mentioned at the bottom of the above page
3. Tried various IP ranges like 10.8.0.0, 10.128.0.0, 10.160.0.0 - no use
4. Created a new project and tried to create the access there, same result
5. **Works** if I change the region to **us-central1** (instead of **asia-south1**). See below

```
gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors create cloud-sql-connector \
    --network default \
    --region us-central1 \
    --range 10.8.0.0/28

Created connector [cloud-sql-connector]

gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors describe cloud-sql-connector --region us-central1

ipCidrRange: 10.8.0.0/28
maxThroughput: 300
minThroughput: 200
name: projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1/connectors/cloud-sql-connector
network: default
state: READY
```

6. **Fails** if try with **asia/south1** (part of the [supported regions](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#supported_regions) as per the documentation)

```
gcloud compute networks vpc-access connectors create sql-connector \
    --network default \
    --region asia-south1 \
    --range 10.8.0.0/28

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.networks.vpc-access.connectors.create) {
  "code": 13,
  "message": "An internal error occurred: Failed to create a VPC Access connector. Please delete the connector manually."
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an ongoing issue with that specific region as it is out of capacity.

When I try to create the connector using the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#creating_a_connector) instead of the relevant gcloud commands the asia-south1 region doesn't even show up.

Notice that you are not the only user reporting this issue. I will recommend you to star and monitor the following [Public Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/164378672) from GCP's Issue Tracker to get the most updated information from the relevant team.

Comment: Thanks.. that helps.. let me follow the issue