# Unable to create a serverless vpc access connector in Google Cloud asia-south1 (Mumbai) region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc

I am trying to create a **serverless vpc connector** in **asia-south1(Mumbai) region** in **Google Cloud**. But everytime I try, I get a message, error creating vpc connector. I have tried with other regions(us-central1, europe-west1, asia-southeast2) etc and it is working fine. But I am getting error while creating it in asia-south1(Mumbai) region.

I am using the following parameters:

- asia-south1
- default network
- 10.8.0.0
- 200mbps min
- 300mbps max

Kindly help me resolve the issue

Comment: Have you tried the steps mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#troubleshooting).

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64373810/error-while-creating-gcp-serverless-vpc-connection-code-13) and a [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/164378672) has been posted on the GCP issue tracker. You can star/follow it to get future updates.