# VPC Access connector failed to get healthy

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am getting below error while trying to create VPC Access connector in GCP region `us-central1`:

```
An internal error occurred: VPC Access connector failed to get healthy. Please check GCE quotas, logs and org policies and recreate.
```

I also tried to create the VPC access connector in region us-east1 but got the same issue.

I tried searching for existing bugs on [gcp issues portal](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=Serverless%20VPC%20Connector%20in%20us-central1) but could not find this issue.

I have tried to follow [image access constraint](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/restricting-image-access#trusted_images) but I don't have an organisation so I am unable to edit the required policy.

Comment: It can either be an internal IP subnet issue or you are missing the required image access constraint. Please read through this document where these issues are discussed in detail[1]
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#errors

Comment: @JamesS Thanks but I don't belong to any organisation that is why I don't see the edit option in image access constraint page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having the same issue. After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64373810/error-while-creating-gcp-serverless-vpc-connection-code-13) I checked different regions with exactly the same configuration:

```
Network: Default
Subnet: Custom IP range
IP range: 10.8.0.0/28
```

I can confirm that changing the area solves the issue. In my case, and as an example, I proceeded successfully with **australia-southeast2**. In your case, could be someone else.

Basically, when creating a VPC connector in Google Cloud, we have some regions working and some others are not. It may be a capacity problem over some Google regions.

Comment: This was my issue as well - it's not at all clear - especially as it's possible to choose many unsupported regions from the dropdown when setting it up!
In my case I had to choose europe-west1, rather than europe-west2 (where the rest of the infra is located)

Comment: Having said that - today when I tried it, europe-west2 seemed to be fine...

Answer (score 1):

It can be an internal IP subnet assignment issue. This subnet must be used exclusively by the connector per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#:%7E:text=Important%3A%20Every,and%20NAT%20configurations.)

> Every VPC connector requires its own /28 subnet to place connector instances on; this subnet must not have any other resources on it other than the VPC connector. If you don't use Shared VPC, you can either create a subnet for the connector to use, or specify an unused custom IP range for the connector to create a subnet for its use. If you choose the custom IP range, the subnet that is created is hidden and cannot be used in firewall rules and NAT configurations.

Or it can also be that you are missing the required image access constraint. In this case, you may follow this step by step guide in [seting image access constraints](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/restricting-image-access#trusted_images)

1. Go to the Organization policies page.
2. In the policies list, click Define trusted image projects.
3. Click Edit to customize your existing trusted image constraints.
4. On the Edit page, select Customize.
5. In the Policy values drop-down list, select Custom to set the constraint on specific image projects.
6. In the Policy type drop-down list, specify a value as follows:
   -To restrict the specified image projects, select `Deny`.

   -To remove restrictions for the specified image projects, select `Allow`.
7. In the Custom values field, enter the names of image projects using projects/IMAGE_PROJECT format. Replace IMAGE_PROJECT with the image project you want in this case “serverless-vpc-access-images“ to set constraints on. If you are setting project-level constraints, then they might conflict with the existing constraints set on your organization or folder.
8. Click New policy value to add multiple image projects.
9. Click Save to apply the constraint.

Additionally, please make sure that there are no firewall rules on your VPC network with a priority before 1000 that deny ingress from your connector's IP range.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see the edit option probably because I don't belong to any organisation